# How does this function work "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" [rand()%26]?

Tags: c, random, generate

To generate random letters of the alphabet

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" [rand()%26]
```

How does this work?

Answer (score 8):

In fact this expression

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" [rand()%26]
```

is equivalent to

char *p = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

```
p[rand()%26]
```

That is a random character is selected from a string literal by using the subscript operator.

The string literal used in the original expression is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

The expression `rand()%26` yields a random value (remainder) in the range `[0, 25]`

Answer (score 4):

A *string literal* is an array expression, and as such you can subscript it like any other array expression<sup>1</sup>.

It's equivalent to writing:

```
const char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int idx = rand() % 26;
char c = alphabet[idx];
```

`rand() % 26` returns a (pseudo)random value in the range `[0..25]`, and that's used to index into the alphabet array.

You don't often see literals be subscripted like that because it's hard to read and not always obvious.

---

1. Strictly speaking, the expression "decays" to type `char *`, and that's what the `[]` operator is applied to.

Answer (score 3):

String literals in C are really *arrays* (that as usual decay to pointers to their first element). And you can index those arrays like any other array (which is what's happening here).